# Configuring a Google Cloud Compute Instance via SSH, session closes, all data lost?

Tags: centos, google-cloud-platform

I have a new CentOS instance and would like to configure the environment. I'm using the SSH in the browser to configure. All goes well with installing apache and various other packages and I am able to use the ip to get both the default page and a php test page.  At some point, the session abruptly ends.  I see in the Compute Engine page that the IP changed.  When I SSH into it again, it's a blank slate and none of the changes I made are there.
Is this expected behavior?
I'm guessing I'm missing something.
Trial period user.
Firewall is open to http and https traffic.

Comment: what is that point when the session ends?

Comment: Is this server part of an auto-scaling group (or whatever Google calls it)?

Comment: Yes, its on a CPU autoscale at 80% threshold, min 1, max 6.
Currently the CPU is at 0.00 - 0.03% usage - typical for a machine that isn't serving live traffic.
Session ends abruptly, at one point it ended while yum was doing an install.

Comment: Went through another config and it held for at least 30 minutes which was a good sign.  I re-loaded the Google Cloud website UI and then I received the message in the SSH window and the instance status icon 'spun' until a new IP was shown.  The SSH window message was "The SSH connection to VM instance 'web-instance' was lost. Learn more about improving SSH session persistence."  The new IP holds none of the updates or installs that were previously done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, two things here: First, the servers are being shut down and replaced likely because you have the health check misconfigured. Second, of course the new servers don't carry your changes over, because they're started with an image that doesn't have your changes.

When using an auto-scaling group, each server should: 1) be completely stateless and 2) have all application code, configuration, and dependencies baked into the image or have the system automatically configure itself on boot.

I would recommend that you take a step back from your auto scaling group until you're able to get a better handle on things. Once you have your server configured *outside* of the auto-scaling group, then make an image of it and use that when configuring your auto-scaling group.

If you want to really step your game, have the server configure itself on boot, using a configuration management system of your choice. I prefer Ansible for this, but any of them will work. Using a configuration management system like this not only allows you to track configuration changes over time in version control but it also keep you honest, in that you're assured that you can rebuild a server from the ground up automatically, within minutes at any time, and when things have to happen automatically, you're unable to hand-configure things (this is a very good thing).

Comment: Great advice and insight.  No idea why this rudimentary issue isn't covered in the docs (or at least the 6-7 hours I spent searching for it).  Strange that 80% CPU threshold is somehow being tripped.

Comment: Well, it's probably assumed that users understand that any changes made to an instance are lost, due to the fact that each instance gets started with the same image.